# How to blend tracks in melt framework?

Tags: melt

Is there any filters/transtions which could be used to [blend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) tracks?

Answer (score 0):

Using `qtblend` transition will meet the requirement.

Here is the sample which demonstrates how to apply the blend mode "darken" to tracks:

```
qmelt \
-video-track example1.mp4 out=:12.0 \
-video-track example2.mp4 out=:12.0 \
-transition qtblend compositing=16 in=:0.0 out=:12.0
```

The value of compositing which represents the blend mode is from [QPainter Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum).

[This video](https://hk1229.cn/blog/assets/melt-plugins-review/transition_qtblend.mp4) is produced by Melt with crop, affine, sepia and qtblend.